# Center one UL, place the other to the right

Tags: html, css, sass

I have my navigation bar consisting of 2 ul's, one ul i want to be centered the other i want to the far right.

I originally had them both in the same ul, but realised that made me unable to move the last one to right while keeping the rest centered. So I created another ul and gave it the exact same styling, which gave me the problem of them not being on the same line. This i fixed by throwing `dislay: inline-block` on both of them, but that now prevents me from moving the ul's.

Here is my sass:

```
.navbar {
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444444;
}

.navbar-content-center {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    a {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px 25px;
      &:hover:not(.active) {
        color: #e6c48a;
      }
    }
  }
}

.navbar-content-right {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #444444;
  border: 1px #444444 solid;
  justify-content: right;
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: right;
    text-align: right;
    a {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px 25px;
      &:hover:not(.active) {
        color: #e6c48a;
      }
    }
  }
}

.active {
  color: #e6c48a;
}
```

and my html:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "NavigationBar",
  data() {
    return {
      isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem("user")
    };
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-content-center">
      <li>
        <router-link v-bind:to="'/'" :key="1">Home</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link v-bind:to="'/language'" :key="2">Language</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link v-bind:to="'/topics'" :key="3">Topic</router-link>
      </li>
      <li v-if="!isLoggedIn">
        <router-link v-bind:to="'/login'" :key="4">Login</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-content-right">
      <li v-if="isLoggedIn">
        <router-link to="/profile" :key="5">Profile</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "./NavigationBar.scss";
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I understood you:

```css
.navbar {
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.navbar-content {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-content li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-content li:first-of-type {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  justify-content: left;
}

.navbar-content li:last-of-type {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">

  <ul class="navbar-content">
    <li>
      <!-- for balance, maybe later you'll add content -->
    </li>

    <li>
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/'" :key="1">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/language'" :key="2">Language</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/topics'" :key="3">Topic</router-link>
    </li>
    <li v-if="!isLoggedIn">
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/login'" :key="4">Login</router-link>
    </li>

    <li v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <router-link to="/profile" :key="5">Profile</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But this feels a little empty on the left; a little out of balance.

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.navbar-content {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-content li {
  margin: 15px 5px;
}

.navbar-content:last-child {
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">

  <ul class="navbar-content">
    <li>
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/'" :key="1">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/language'" :key="2">Language</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/topics'" :key="3">Topic</router-link>
    </li>
    <li v-if="!isLoggedIn">
      <router-link v-bind:to="'/login'" :key="4">Login</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-content">
    <li v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <router-link to="/profile" :key="5">Profile</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But centering the left menu in the free space doesn't feel right either.
Maybe you want to put some Icon or logo or company name or something on the left in the first example, so that it ain't that empty.

---

If you're sure that you'll never need this `<li>` at the beginning, that it will never contain content, you can replace it and its style with a pseudo-element.

```
.navbar-content::before {
  content: " ";
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, it solved my problem! Thank you so much :)